# What is the best way to integrate Angular2 with Salesforce?

Tags: angular, salesforce, integration, visualforce, force.com

I'm a salesforce developer and I wonder what is the best way to integrate Angular2 with Salesforce. So far I did some work using gulp and webpack, but I wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of tutorials how to use Angular2 and Salesforce together, for instance:

- [Angular 2 with VisualForce](http://www.ngpillango.com/?p=7)
- [Sample Application with Angular 2 and Salesforce REST Services](http://coenraets.org/blog/2015/12/angular2-rest-salesforce/)

Maybe you have some specific question related to this topic?